# Замена текста происходит только один раз несмотря на наличие цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, циклы

В данном случае foundRegular - список из двух объектов.
sourse - строчка, в которой они оба встречаются. Каждый из них нужно заменить на replasement, но заменяется только первый. Понимаю, что у меня неправильно:

```
    for i in foundRegular:
        simpleResult = sourse.replace(i, replasement)
        return simpleResult
```

Например:

```
 sourse = '%розы% голубые, %хризантемы% синие'
 foundRegular = ['%розы%', '%хризантемы%']
 replasement = 'цветы'
```

Как реализовать замену нескольких объектов? Чтобы получилось:

> цветы голубые, цветы синие

Comment: потому что return прерывает выполнение функции

Comment: если return оставить после цикла, то заменяется только последний. я не совсем понимаю, можно ли сразу вывести строку без каких-то дополнительных манипуляций.

Comment: source - строчка, пусть например 'obj1_0bj2`.  foundRegular  список объектов. что значит, объекты встречаются в строке? Приведите в вопросе образец входных данных и что получить хотите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про ретурн уже написали в комментариях. Но у вас есть ещё одна ошибка.

В этой строчке:

```
simpleResult = sourse.replace(i, replasement)
```

вы всегда производите одну замену в исходном `sourse`. То есть не имеет значения, что происходило в предыдущих итерациях цикла, всё равно в итоге у вас будет то, что получится из `sourse` заменой только одного элемента, который идёт последним. Результаты из предыдущих итераций просто потеряются, потому что вы нигде их не сохраняете, а просто каждый раз перезаписываете.

Чтобы результаты не терялись, нужно применять `replace` не к `sourse`, а к тому, что у вас получилось на предыдущей итерации:

```
simpleResult = sourse
for i in foundRegular:
    simpleResult = simpleResult.replace(i, replasement)
return simpleResult
```

Comment: `result = functools.reduce(lambda s, old: s.replace(old, replacement), old_strings, source)`

Comment: @jfs, думаю, автору вопроса пока рано знакомиться с reduce и лямбдами.

Comment: 1- это комментарий, а не ответ 2- содержимое на stack overflow не только и не столько для автора вопроса (95% трафика из поисковиков) 3- писать код нужно для читателя, который знает Питон лучше тебя самого, но который меньше контекстом владеет (иначе говоря, код нужно писать для себя самого из будущего: больше опыта с Питоном, но без памяти о текущей задаче) 4- я лично предпочитаю код с меньшим числом движущихся частей, но в с случае с reduce не очевидно, какой код более читаем. Каждый случай отдельно рассматривать стоит. reduce`ом легко злоупотребить, но это полезный элемент..

Comment: .. функционального программирования. В силу вышеперечисленного, я как комментарий вариант с reduce опубликовал.